# How is the GLM '*' operator on quaternion and vec3 defined?

Tags: opengl, quaternion, glm

[Using the definition of quaternion rotation given here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-17-winter/Papers/quaternion.pdf):

[image: Diagram showing quaternion transformation and formula]

So the equivalent code in GLM of the above formula would be like this:

```
glm::quat q;
glm::vec3 v;
glm::vec3 rotated_vector = q * v;
```

and the `rotated_vector` above is the result of applying the `Lq` transformation to vector `v`.

Am I right on this?

Here's the testing code I wrote(not exhaustive):

```
for (size_t number_of_conducted_testing = 0; number_of_conducted_testing < 10000; number_of_conducted_testing++)
{
    //axis to rotate around
    glm::vec3 axis = glm::sphericalRand(1.0);
    //vector to be rotated
    glm::vec3 v    = glm::sphericalRand(1.0);
    //quaternion
    glm::quat q;

    for (auto degree = 0.f; degree < 370.f; degree += 0.0001f)
    {
        q = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(degree), axis);
        glm::vec3 q_vector = glm::vec3(q.x, q.y, q.z);


        const glm::vec3 rotated_vector   = q * v;
        const glm::vec3 rotated_vector_0 = ((q.w) * (q.w) - glm::length2(q_vector)) * v + 2 * (glm::dot(q_vector, v)) * q_vector + 2 * q.w * (glm::cross(q_vector, v));

        float difference = 0.0f;
        if (!test_similarity(rotated_vector, rotated_vector_0, difference))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("two vectors are different!");
        }
    }
}


bool App::test_similarity(glm::vec3 a, glm::vec3 b,float& difference)
{
    const auto difference = glm::length((a - b));
    return difference < 1e-5f;
}
```

And it didn't throw any exception for the case `difference < 0.00001`.

Comment: This sounds like something you can test by listing out a few cases of vectors and quaternions, computing the resulting vector on paper and via code, and comparing the results. What do you observe when you do this test?

Comment: Sir,I updated my post.However I'm not sure if the `difference < 0.00001` is good enough to justify two vectors are close enough.

Comment: You tested 10 000 * 3 700 000 = 37 trillion random vector rotations, none of which differed by 10 micrometers if your base unit were a meter, and you're still uncertain whether `*` is implemented in a completely different way?

Comment: I'd recommend posting your test code and results below as an Answer, giving strong evidence that these formulas are performing the same transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the implementation of GLM '*' operator in **Kavan, Ladislav, et al., "*Geometric skinning with approximate dual quaternion blending.*" ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG) 27.4 (2008): 105**:

> **Lemma 4.** *Let \$\textbf{q} = a + \textbf{r}\$ be a unit regular quaternion with scalar part \$a\$ and vector part \$\textbf{r}\$. Rotation of a vector \$(v_0, v_1, v_2)\$ represented by the regular quaternion \$\textbf{v} = v_0i + v_1j + v_2k\$ can be computed as*
> $$\textbf{v}' = \textbf{v} + 2\textbf{r} \times (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v} + a\textbf{v})\tag{15}$$
> *where \$\textbf{v}′\$ is the vector \$\textbf{v}\$ rotated by \$\textbf{q}\$*.
>
> *Proof.* The proof consists of re-arranging the well-known expression \$\textbf{v}′ = \textbf{qvq}^∗\$. Using Equation (14), we can expand
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \textbf{v}′ &= \textbf{qvq}^∗ = (a + \textbf{r})\textbf{v}(a − \textbf{r}) = (−\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle + a\textbf{v} + \textbf{r} \times \textbf{v})(a − \textbf{r}) = \\
> &= −a\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle + a\langle\textbf{v}, \textbf{r}\rangle + \langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle\textbf{r} + a^2\textbf{v} + a(\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) − a(\textbf{v} \times \textbf{r}) −
> (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) \times \textbf{r} = \\
> &= \langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle\textbf{r} + a^2\textbf{v} + 2a(\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) + \textbf{r} \times (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v})
> \end{align}
> $$
> Recall Lagrange’s formula
> $$ \textbf{r} \times (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) = \textbf{r}\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle − \textbf{v}\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{r}\rangle $$
> which, added to the previous equation, results in
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \textbf{v}′ &= \langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle\textbf{r} + a^2\textbf{v} + 2a(\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) + 2\textbf{r} \times (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) − \textbf{r}\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}\rangle + \textbf{v}\langle\textbf{r}, \textbf{r}\rangle = \\
> &= \textbf{v}(a^2 + \Vert\textbf{r}\Vert^2 ) + 2a(\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}) + 2\textbf{r} \times (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{v})
> \end{align}
> $$
> from which Equation (15) readily follows.

And it's exactly how GLM implements its '*' operator on quaternion and vec3:

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER GLM_CONSTEXPR vec<3, T, Q> operator*(qua<T, Q> const& q, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    vec<3, T, Q> const QuatVector(q.x, q.y, q.z);
    vec<3, T, Q> const uv(glm::cross(QuatVector, v));
    vec<3, T, Q> const uuv(glm::cross(QuatVector, uv));

    return v + ((uv * q.w) + uuv) * static_cast<T>(2);
}
```